# Makefile.am/Configure.ac Conditional Environment Variable Check

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, automake, gcov

I am trying to enable and disable compile flags for gcov in C++ on Linux. I do not want to have the gcov flags set at all times. I only want them set when I am testing the software. The environment variable I am checking is called TESTENABLED.

In my configure.ac file I have the following line:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLEGCOV],[test x$TESTENABLED = xtrue])
```

In my Makefile.am file I have the following lines:

```
if ENABLEGCOV
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
else
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Wall
endif
```

However when I build my program I notice that it is not setting AM_CXXFLAGS correctly. So none of my gcov .gcno/.gcda files are being generated. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if anyone has something to say they will do so; even without you reminding them (this is not a mailinglist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your environment variable set to `true`, or probably to some other truish-value (e.g. `1`)?

In any case, the usual way would be add a flag to `configure` that turns on a certain feature. The following `configure.ac` snippet adds a `--enable-gcov` flag to configure; it will also do a printout whether it has enabled gcov or not:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(gcov,[AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-gcov], [enable coverage test])])
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether to enable gcov])
AS_IF([test "x${enable_gcov}" = "xyes" ], AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]), AC_MSG_RESULT([no]))
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLEGCOV],[test "x${enable_gcov}" = "xyes"])
```

I also find `Makefile.am` more easy to read by just *adding* flags to `CXXFLAGS` if a certain condition is met:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC
if ENABLEGCOV
AM_CXXFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Currently the project has two Makefile.am. One is in the main directory where there is a configure.ac and then the other is on a sub directory called src. I have been doing the following commands to remake the makefiles when I update them. "automake src/Makefile" and "automake Makefile". I have made my changes to the configure.ac in the main directory and then use the conditional if ENABLEGCOV inside my src/Makefile.am. However it still does not work. I currently have my environment variable defined as the following: export USEGCOV = "true". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fixed my problem but your solution was correct! Thank you! I realized that you also have to do "autoconf" to update the configure.ac file after you modify it. I also did not need the "x" in the commands. So for example I just used "AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLEGCOV],[test "${USE_GCOV}" = "true"]) with my environment variable set with the following: "export USE_GCOV="true" ".

Comment: the `test "x${FOO}"` idiom is mainly to protect against empty FOOs; while it might work with `FOO=yes` it might fail if you don't care about setting *FOO*.

Comment: why don't you add "-lgcov" anywhere? Is "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" enough?

Comment: @Arkady because this is not what the OP asked: the question was about how to conditionally add some flags; the actual nature of these flags is irrelevant for the question.